# AWS Wrangler - Pandas red_sql to S3 in a limited memory environment

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, memory-management, parquet

I am looking for a way to extract data from a database and push that data into a parquet dataset in S3 in a environment with limited memory. If I proceed like this:

```
with someDB.connect() as connect:
    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table", connect)
    wr.s3.to_parquet(df, dataset=True, path="s3://flo-bucket/")
```

The Pandas data frame (df) is fully loaded in memory then pushed to S3 by wrangler. So if the data frame is too big, the operation fails. I would like to chunk the data frame and pass those chunks to a process (does not have to be wrangler) that would progressively send them to S3 in parquet format. Is this possible? I found examples using an IO buffer for a CSV file but I don't think it's possible with parquet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to read the data in small chunks as it is available in `read_sql` function.

try something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import awswrangler as wr

path='s3://bucket/prefix'

def write_parquet_chunk(chunk, path, index=False):
    wr.s3.to_parquet(
        df=chunk,
        path=path,
        dataset=True,
        mode="append",
        index=index
    )

chunksize = 100

with someDB.connect() as connect:
    query = "SELECT * FROM table"
    chunks = pd.read_sql(query, connect, chunksize=chunksize)

    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        print(f"Processing chunk {i+1}")
        write_parquet_chunk(chunk, path)
```

Ref:
https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.read_parquet.html